# How to access UILabel created programmatically without tag?

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, uilabel

I am new to iOS development, working on an iPad app, having XIBs with a lot of UI elements, so I want to create them programmatically and get data from these Labels and TextFields. 
So how to access these fields without using tags, is there any way to access them ?

Comment: Google with `IBOutlet`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code gets all the labels in a view controller, If you want to find all the text fields replace UILabel with UITextfield

```
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 30)];
[lbl setText:@"Hello World"];
[self.view addSubview:lbl];
for(id x in [self.view subviews])
{
    if([x isMemberOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do but here,

You can get the properties and/or values of Labels or TextFields by these:

```
for(UILabel *lbl in self.view.subviews) {
    // get labels properties here
    NSLog(@"Label : %@", lbl.text);

}

for(UITextField *tf in self.view.subviews) {
    // get the textfield properties here
    NSLog(@"TextField : %@", tf.text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

declare it in .h file as like follow

```
UILabel * userName;
```

and access it in .m file directly with using of it's name (userName) no need for Tag here
i.e.

```
NSLog(@"userName %@",userName);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your .h file, make IBOutlet like this :

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl;
```

In your nib or storyboard. Right click your View Controller. You will get a list, select "lbl" (in this case) from your `Outlet` and drag it to the "lbl" and connect. You can now access this label by writing `self.lbl` anywhere in your View Controller

Comment: OP mentioned that he's creating labels in code, so this won't work.